# Why does it show "Visit Website" and not Add extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app, manifest.json

I would like publish a website (web app) on our intranet as chrome app in the google web store.
I want to publish this app to all Computers in my domain, I've seen that I can do this with the GPO of Google and it works with every extension but not with mine.

So the problem I ran into is that if I publish my app in the chrome web store you can't download it. It only says "Visit Website". As shown in the picture here: [Visit Website Button in the web store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffKhV.png)

This is how my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Support-Ticket",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "https://intranet.*.com/example"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://intranet.*.com/example"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

I've tested it with another little app where the manifest looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Support Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
      "128":"128.png"
     },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {}, 
    "permissions":[        
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background":{        
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

And the .js like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('index.html')}, function(tab) {
        // Tab opened.
    });
});
```

I would like to have this website as chrome app and than install it on all computers in my domain with a shortcut in the Start Menu or Desktop.

Comment: You can't. 1) Chrome app is not a PWA. 2) Inline installs have been disabled for chrome apps/extensions.

Comment: did you find out the reason for this?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I managed to create the app and display the intranet on the app with the html tag "webview".

Now it looks like this:
[Window Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2VbD.png)

Does anyone know how I can change the color of the window frame to a darker grey?

Comment: You need to create a [frameless app window](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window) and draw the title bar yourself via CSS/HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to create a shortcut that works for every user to open the app?

Comment: I've meant a shortcut to open. For example "Shortcut.lnk" and if I open this it should open my app.

Comment: Go to `chrome://apps`, right-click your app and create a shortcut.

Comment: But I want a shortcut that works for every user. In the shortcut you create with "create a shortcut" there is this line: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --user-data-dir="C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Roaming\Google\Chrome\User Data" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ogpdpankijhiloielldkcodjnhkjjjci

Comment: Well, try editing the shortcut and remove the extra parameters. Anyway, I don't know so ask a new question, maybe someone else knows.